# $D_3 \simeq S_3$ why can't we map elements to different orders from the element itself?

Tags: group-theory

We know that $D_3 =\{e,r,r^2,s,rs,r^2s\}$ and

$S_3$ has the following elements: $(12),(23),(13),(123),(213),e$

Why is it that we **can't** map elements in $D_3$ to different orders in $S_3$, in particular why can't we map $e \mapsto (12)?$

I know that the function WILL NOT hold the homomorphism property but why is it that we map the same orders to each other? By what theorem or proposition? Please help!!!

Comment: $\phi(x^n) = \phi(x)^n$.

Comment: You absolutely **can** map elements to elements of different orders, if you're willing to violate the homomorphism property. But, what use is a map that violates the homomorphism property?

Comment: We don't because of the reason you mentioned-- if we do that then our mapping fails to be a homomorphism (and thus fails to be an isomorphism). There's no theorem or proposition at play here. If you wanted to you could define some function mapping $D_3 \ni e \mapsto (1\ 2) \in S_3$, but why bother?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think my question was clear, sorry. I'm more asking why is that it guarentees the homomorphism IF we do map it to the same orders?

Comment: @Skypanties: It doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Let me rephrase your question first in order to make sure I understand what is being asked:

> If $\phi:G\rightarrow \phi(G)\subseteq H$ is a mapping between two groups that preserves the order of elements, then is $\phi$ a group homomorphism?

The answer to this is no. Take $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_6\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ where 
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases} 4 & \text{x=2}\\
2 & \text{x=4}\\
x & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Since $|4|=|2|=3 \in \mathbb{Z}_6$ we have that $\phi$ preserves the order of elements, but 
$$4 = \phi(2) = \phi(1+1)\neq \phi(1)+\phi(1) = 2 $$

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism between groups must map the set of domain elements of each order to the corresponding set in the codomain.

Your comment seems to be asking about the converse.

The converse is false. If in the isomorphism you have from $D_3$ to $S_3$ you swap the values for the elements of order $2$ you will no longer satisfy the homomorphism condition.